# change default font SSRS Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, layout, reporting-services, fonts, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been searching hi and lo, within and outside internet but it seems I cannot find a definitive answer:
Can I change the default layout-items in SSRS reports? If so, how?

- So that a textbox does not have Arial 10 as default fontsize but has fontsize 8?
- So that tablixes have default properties like 'show column-headers on each page' enabled?
- and so on?

I am familiar with custom templates (.rdl) but they do not offer the possibility of changing layout-items like default font and colors and properties of report parts and such.

In VS 2005 there was the StyleTemplate to play with but that is only effective when using the wizard.
It seems it is the same way with VS 2010.

I prefer to hear that it can be done and instructions how to, I would be satisfied with tips how to circumvent the problem of manually changing those properties eacht time and I will be grateful for a definitive answer. Right now it is driving me crazy :)

I am working with VS2010 (latest updates and such) icm SQL 2008, 2008R2 and (local) 2012BI

Thanks for thinking with me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately by design, you are not allowed to set default font etc. There is active defect in Microsoft https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/574003/modify-the-default-font-family-for-sql-server-business-intelligence-development-studio-while-creating-a-report#

Comment: The (or A) problem with MS is the lack of the Avis effect; it's hard to get up in the morning when you're wearing silk pajamas.

Answer (score 9):

I know it's a very old post, but for others in search of an answer, I thought I'd add the following. If I want all my textboxes in a font other than Arial 10pt, I will make the first textbox and set my font styling, then use that as a master textbox, copying it and changing the interior text rather than creating new textboxes each time. It's a hack, but since VS still can't do this in 2015, it's the best we have.

Answer (score 4):

You can always open code(XML)-view and edit font properties there. Eg. search for
    <FontFamily> -tag and add      <FontSize>10pt</FontSize> as a sibling for <Style>-tag.

Before editing the XML, close report design-view. Otherwise properties of objects are not functioning properly.

Comment: This worked, but even after closing design view, making the changes in XML/.rdl file and reopening the design view, the Preview tab was fouled up for awhile - said there was an error, wouldn't afford my report params. But then - with no further action on my part that didn't involve the yanking of follicles and gnashing of choppers - it "woke up and smelled the coffee" and decided everything was hunky dory after all.

Answer (score 2):

At the start of the XML for the RDL file (what you see if you select View Code on the file) there's a tag `<df:DefaultFontFamily>` which defines the default font. If you change this to the family you want and re-save the XML file, any future textboxes you create will pick up this default font family.

Answer (score 0):

The FontSize property must be in *n*pt format. If this property takes the value from an SQL query that returns an integer, add the expression by adding "pt": (for example, = Fields! DimFont.Value & "pt").